# Java Checkbook Balancer

Tags: java, iteration

I'm having trouble correcting the below code. It doesn't give me any syntax error, but I know there's some logic code behind it and I can't point it out, and correct it.

I'm still new to coding so I have to learn from your assistance on this.
Thank you!

Here's the problem that I'm supposed to make the code on:

```
Make a simple checkbook balancer that would input a sequence of 
deposits (positive floating-point values) and 
issuances (negative floating-point values) terminated by a 0. 
It would output the transaction type, the amount and the running balance for each entry. 
Assume the initial balance of 0. Ensure that the issued check won’t bounce!
```

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Checkbook{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        float bal=0, amt=0;
        char reply;

        do{
            System.out.print("Input Amount: ");
            amt=input.nextInt();
            if(amt>0){

                bal+=amt;

                System.out.print("\nAmount: " +amt);
                System.out.print("\nTransaction Line: Deposit");
                System.out.print("\nRunning Balance: " +bal);
                ;
                }


            else if(amt<0 ){

                bal-=amt;

                System.out.print("\nAmount: " +Math.abs(amt));
                System.out.print("\nTransaction Line: Issuance");
                System.out.print("\nRunning Balance: " +bal);
                ;
                }
            else

                do{
                            System.out.println("Hello world!");
                            System.out.println("Again? [y/n]");
                            reply=input.next().charAt(0);   
                }while(reply!='n');



        }while(bal!=0);

    }
}
```

This is how it currently looks like.
[image]

Comment: One thing that certainly isn't right is that you print the same variable/value for "Amount", "Transaction Line" and "Running Balance" almost everywhere. I'm sure that the variable `amt` doesn't represent all those values

Comment: Oh right, thanks for noticing that. My eyes are twisted by looking at the code. I've edited that bit but now it only adds the bal and amount, and not subtracting it even though it's a negative. I'm updated the question with latest changes too

Comment: Please format your code properly. It'll make your code better readable, for both yourself and future readers.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to place the input amount in the next line though. It really starts from the top. and it doesnt end